# With Yarn workspaces, how can compiled binaries be linked to the workspace post-compilation?

Tags: symlink, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

**Context**

Yarn workspaces provide for a convenient mono-repo-like functionality where packages are automatically linked. I.e. they can require/import each other, and their binaries are linked and accessible from the workspace root.

An example:

*workspace/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "200180719-yarn-bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "private": true
}
```

*workspace/packages/a/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "mycli": "src/index.js"
  }
}
```

*workspace/packages/a/src/index.js*

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('welcome to the cli')
```

If you then change directory to the main workspace and run `yarn install`, yarn correctly links the binaries and you can run:

```
yarn run mycli
```

From the workspace directory just fine. Great!

**Problem**

The problem I have is that if your code first has to be compiled, the binary won't be available before `yarn install` has finished (since you are not supposed to ship compiled code in version control). I use Typescript to compile my cli:

Rename `index.js` to `index.ts` and update `a/package.json` to:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "mycli": "dist/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc src/index.ts --outDir dist",
    "preinstall": "yarn run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Even though `dist/index.js` is correctly build when you run `yarn install` on the workspace directory, it fails to create a link to the binary:

```
Toms-MacBook-Pro-2:200180719-yarn-bin tommedema$ yarn run mycli
yarn run v1.7.0
error Command "mycli" not found.
```

**Question**

How can I make yarn workspace binary linking work when my binaries need to be compiled on install?

If I need to use Lerna to make this work, that would be totally fine too (though preferably avoiding a call to `lerna bootstrap` since that should be redundant with yarn workspaces).

Comment: (I like to post this like a comment but I can't) I like to share this links that can be of help: [workspaces "bin" symlinks not created for sub-dependencies](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4964) [Workspace bin files aren't linked or installed in root](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3846)